# get xml node child element value based on the parent attribute value

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I've one xml like:-

```
 <SkillMap>
   <ExitPoint ID="01">
    <NodeName>abcd</NodeName>
   </ExitPoint>
   <ExitPoint ID="04">
    <NodeName>defg</NodeName>
   </ExitPoint>
   <ExitPoint ID="22">
    <NodeName>mnop</NodeName>
   </ExitPoint>
  </SkillMap>
```

I am trying to get the value of the `<ExitPoint>` node based on the ID value i.e. if i enter the ID as 01 it should give "abcd" and if 22 it should give "mnop" and so on, but i'm not getting it, tried lot, please help.

Thanks,
Ars

Comment: You should you use Xpath for that.

Comment: what you have tried so far? have you faced any issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [Xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp), consider the following example taken from the [JAXP Specification 1.4](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=206) (which I recommend you to consult for this):

```
// parse the XML as a W3C Document
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
org.w3c.Document document = builder.parse(new File("/widgets.xml"));
// evaluate the XPath expression against the Document
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "/widgets/widget[@name='a']/@quantity";
Double quantity = (Double) xpath.evaluate(expression, document, XPathConstants.NUMBER);
```

Comment: thanks but for the above xml whether i've to use
`String expression = "/ExitPoint/widget[@name='ID']/@quantity";`
or wat?

Comment: I think that if you read the material I have shared in my answer, you will eventually be capable of figuring out yourself. And I think that's the way it should be.